# Is it possible to use Azure AD for 2fa with the proposed scenario?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

An existing user of my website attempts to login using their email address, I check a 2fa table in my DB to see if this user has transitioned to 2fa if not I ask for their password and authenticate them, if successful I send them to azure where they create an account using ANY email address/password of their choosing.  Azure sends back a user identitifer to my websites endpoint that I can then create a record of in my 2fa table for this user. Going forward when this user logs in to my website they will enter their username, i will see from my 2fa table that they have transitioned to 2fa and I will redirect them to azure and they will login with whatever credentials they created.   Is this possible?  If not is it possible to do something similar that doesn't require me to have to manually setup a guest account in azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use the [Microsoft Graph API Create User endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create new tenant users.
2. Use [Microsoft Graph API Create invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to add a [guest user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-properties) and later display or redirect him to a [Direct Redemption Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/redemption-experience#redemption-through-a-direct-link)

Please let us know if you need additional assistance.